# jQuery onepage-scroll with a scrollable div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onepage-scroll

I'm currently using the onepage-scroll plug-in to create a kind of slideshow / onepager. But within the page I also have a part of content through which I would like visitor be able to scroll (as the div overflows the screen).

Is is possible to have this combined with the onepage-scroll plug-in? As now, when you try to scroll through the div, you move to the next "slide"

Example: https://imrafaelhi.nl/

Answer (score 0):

Please use scroll event on specific div not with the window. Thus you can disable the scroll event on specific divs by using CSS.

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow what you are meaning here.